# I'm stuck with a logistics formula I need for a simple game

Tags: math, formula

i'm a bit stuck with a calculation and I hope someone can help me to solve this.

I want to calculate an x amounts of containes that needs to be delivered within a certain period of days, taking in account that a truck with one container takes an x amount of days to deliver one container and return to reload again.

I want to calculate / create a formula how many trucks I need to deliver all the containers within the maximum amount of days that are given.

So I have the following variables:

- Total amount of truck containers
- Maximum window of days to deliver all the containers
- Days that one truck needs to make one round

For example:

5 containers
21 day to deliver all the containers
7 days a truck needs to make one round

I use the following calculation:

5 (containers) / 23 (days to deliver) * 7 (days to make one round) = 1,52 trucks needed

30 (containers) / 30 (days to deliver) * 7 (days to make one round) = 7 trucks needed (but here I miss one truck, because I need 8 trucks to deliver 30 containers.

I know I'm missing something, but maths are not my strongest field of expertise and can't seem to find what I miss here.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What programming language are you using to write this game?

Comment: Any code to give this question a **direct** relation to programming?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite that simple. If one truck delivers one container at a time, it takes a truck D days to deliver. Then it takes R days to return to the warehouse for the next container.

So the first delivery takes D time, and each subsequent delivery takes R+D time.

Days for 1 truck to make n deliveries is then D + (n-1)*(R+D). Simplifying that's: days = n*(R+D)-R. So the number of deliveries one truck can make in Y days is n = (Y+R)/(R+D).

Now you've got the number of deliveries one truck can make (round down).

So in Y days, if one truck can make n deliveries, you have m = N/n, where m = # trucks, N = total # deliveries, and n = deliveries by one truck. In this case round up.

To check the math, you said 5 containers, 21 days, 7 day round trip which I'll convert to 4+3.

Y=21, D=4, R=3, N=5:   n = (21 + 3)/(4+3) = 24 / 7 = 3.x, round down to 3. Then m = 5/3 = 1.x, round up to 2.

Thinking that out logically, 2 trucks deliver 2 containers in 7 days. 2 trucks deliver an additional two containers in 7 days. That leaves 7 days remaining, one package remaining, one truck delivers it, one truck sits idle that last cycle. So the math checks out.

Comment: Wow, very nice. I could see what it worked out to logically, but I'm not good enough at math to express it in a formula. I've been trying, believe me haha

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! Besides the fact that the formula works like a charm, I also got a better understanding on how to approach these kind of calculations!